# C# Implement cache for WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, caching

I want to implement cache for my WPF application.
My application is holding over Sorry, I read of the wrong count. There is 2328681 items, and what I want to do is to cache all these itemsinto a file saved on the computer or something, which should release the workload of retrieving data from the database on the next runtime.
I'm going to have a function which check the latest DBUpdateTime, which compare if the DBUpdateTime in cache differs from the one in SQL, then retrieve the newest update.

Does someone know how I can achieve this? With what kind of library do you suggest my to use in order to achieve the cache?

I'm going to show active items, but I also want to show inactive items, should I save all itemsin a cache, then filter it by runtime?

Comment: Your question is too broad. Please read our [ask] topics. You should do some research and try something. If you encounter any issues with your attempts, ask a **specific** question on Stack Overflow and describe a **particular** problem, ideally demonstrated by a [mcve].

Comment: `IDictionary<string, YourModel>` will work fine as long as you managed to implement `GetHashCode()` correctly. Don't forget `Equals()` as well. In this case, `string` represents a unique id. Other typical options are: `int`, `long`, `Guid`.

Comment: @SerejaBogolubov is the data going to be saved in cache until next runtime too?

Comment: @KhoaLe, nah, that one is in-memory. You have to decorate it with extra - to write to a disk. Even though, dictionary is a valid way to maintain a quantity you've mentioned. You don't need to write to a disk every time something gets changed, rather schedule IO once per period you'll find acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

With small amounts of data, Serialisation is better than a local database.
In this case it seems you need over 2 million records so you'd need to pull them all into memory to work with them if you stored them in a flat file or memory. 
That sounds like it'd be too much data to handle.

Meaning a local database is very likely your best candidate. Which one suits best depends on how you will access the data and what you'll store.
SQLlite would be a candidate if these are simple records.

If you need to know immediately any change is made to a record then a push mechanism would be an idea.
You could use signalr to tell clients data has changed.

If you don't need to know immediately then you could have the client poll and ask what's changed every once in a while.

What I have done in the past is to add a RecentChanges table per logical entity. When a record is changed a record is added with the id, timestamp and user. You can then read this table to find what's been changed since a specific time. Where heavy usage and database overheads mean a more sophisticated approach I've cached copies of recently changed records on a business server.

Comment: Sorry, I read of the wrong count. There is 2328681 items.

Comment: Local database then.

Comment: would it be deployed with the application? I want the data to fill up at start, if the cache is empty. If the cache is not empty, I want to add/remove/edit to keep it updated. Would local database be the solution for this then?

Comment: You can deploy with file copy. Depending on how dynamic the data is and how quick you need to know of changes you could maybe download a file each night.

Answer (score 1):

Making a dynamic database in a cashe is **wrong**. I think not in one window, you do not call 300,000 records.
Better where you display them, put a limit of 200 records. And make a normal filter, if you have it, optimize your query.
I think instead of 300,000 records, "**REASONABLE**" will show 200, or at will 300, 500, 1000, 10000.
For example, I have a window "Connections" and "Contracts" and plus a Link window. I have about 2 million entries, I show the last 200 by filter.

Comment: My case is that I would like to use all the items to be displayed in a grid, so in my case I would need all the data... But not all the data should be shown all the time.

Comment: I apologize my friend !. But I stay in my. If your data is stored on a remote database, it is not reasonable to show all elements. Please correct the logic of your application. It is not correct to store so much data in the client part.
If you need it, you can make a local database in the client part and make them synchronous.